# Ant not rebuilding Android application with `ant debug install`

Tags: android, ant

Starting with a clean project created with:

```
android create project -n something -t android-7 -p something -k com.example.something -a Something
```

When I run `ant debug install` and open the application in my emulator, I see (as expected)

[image: Emulator screenshot from initial build]

**Here's where it goes bad.** I now change something trivial in the application. In this example, I'm going to remove the `setContentView` call from the main activity so it looks like this:

```
package com.example.something;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class Something extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);   REMOVED
    }
}
```

Now I rebuild the application with `ant debug install` and run it in the emulator. I see this:

[image: Emulator screenshot after rebuild]

This is wrong. I just removed the text with my previous edit. If I do `ant clean` before `ant debug install`, I get the expected result:

[image: Expected result after rebuild]

I don't want to have to run `ant clean` before each time I run `ant debug install`. How can I make ant actually rebuild the program without running `ant clean` each time?

---

**Details:**

Here's the output from the inital `ant debug install`:

```
$ ant debug install
Buildfile: /home/x/android/something/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-setup:
     [echo] Gathering info for something...
    [setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 16
    [setup] Project Target: Android 2.1
    [setup] API level: 7
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] Resolving library dependencies:
    [setup] No library dependencies.
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] 
    [setup] WARNING: No minSdkVersion value set. Application will install on all Android versions.

-build-setup:
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/x/android/something/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/x/android/something/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/x/android/something/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/x/android/something/bin/classes

-pre-build:

-code-gen:
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /home/x/android/something/bin/classes

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /home/x/android/something/bin/classes.dex...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /home/x/android/something/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /home/x/android/something/bin/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...

-package:
[apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.
[apkbuilder] Creating something-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
     [echo] Debug Package: /home/x/android/something/bin/something-debug.apk

debug:
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: /home/x/android/something/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/x/android/something/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/x/android/something/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/x/android/something/bin/build.prop

install:
     [echo] Installing /home/x/android/something/bin/something-debug.apk onto default emulator or device...
     [exec] 66 KB/s (4410 bytes in 0.065s)
     [exec]     pkg: /data/local/tmp/something-debug.apk
     [exec] Success

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 5 seconds
```

Here's the output from the second `ant debug install` after the edit:

```
$ ant debug install
Buildfile: /home/x/android/something/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-setup:
     [echo] Gathering info for something...
    [setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 16
    [setup] Project Target: Android 2.1
    [setup] API level: 7
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] Resolving library dependencies:
    [setup] No library dependencies.
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] 
    [setup] WARNING: No minSdkVersion value set. Application will install on all Android versions.

-build-setup:
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...

-pre-build:

-code-gen:
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] No changed resources. R.java and Manifest.java untouched.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /home/x/android/something/bin/classes

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] No new compiled code. No need to convert bytecode to dalvik format.

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /home/x/android/something/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /home/x/android/something/bin/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] No changed resources or assets. something.ap_ remains untouched

-package:
[apkbuilder] No changes. No need to create apk.

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] No changes. No need to run zip-align on the apk.
     [echo] Debug Package: /home/x/android/something/bin/something-debug.apk

debug:
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/x/android/something/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/x/android/something/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/x/android/something/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/x/android/something/bin/build.prop

install:
     [echo] Installing /home/x/android/something/bin/something-debug.apk onto default emulator or device...
     [exec] 88 KB/s (4410 bytes in 0.048s)
     [exec]     pkg: /data/local/tmp/something-debug.apk
     [exec] Success

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
```

Notice that the `-dex`, `-package`, and `-debug` steps all seem to think that I didn't change anything.

Comment: Exact same problem here since I switched to a new laptop, trying to figure out whats different..  Using sdk r16 with ant 1.8.2.

Comment: Anyone tested if this still happens with the latest r17 update?

Comment: According to bugtracker, it's fixed in new r17 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22948

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just downgraded to SDK r15 — there's no such bug in it.

Downloads are still there:

http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r15-linux.tgz

http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r15-windows.zip

http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r15-windows.exe

http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r15-macosx.zip

Most relevant issue in android's bugtracker for SDK r16 bug:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23141

Answer (score 3):

I was asking about this in #android-dev, apparently there is a bug in sdk r16 which breaks the  and  steps:

21:25 < pfn> I have that exact problem with sdk r16
21:25 < pfn> the answer is to delete classes.dex and yourapp-debug.apk 
             before every ant debug

Unfortunately this fix doesn't seem to work so it seems we're stuck with having a clean build each time.

Comment: Your fix didn't work for me (deleting bin/classes.dex and bin/x-debug.apk), but I'm glad I'm not the only one with this problem.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately turns out it doesn't work for me either so Ive updated the comment to reflect this. I was just glad to find out I wasn't the only one either!

Answer (score 0):

You need  to update the test-project for the changes to get reflected, and then do the ant debug install
1. ~/android-sdks/tools/android update test-project -m ../SampleProject/ -p ../SampleProjectTest/
2. ant debug install

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that works for me:

1. Copy your workspace to another location
2. delete all projects in the current workspace CAUTION do not delete on DISK
3. open the terminal and write the following
   4.Close Eclipse.

   ```
   cd /home/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins
   rm -rf org.eclipse.core.resources
   ```

   - Start Eclipse
   - Do File->Import
   - General->Existing Projects into Workspace
   - Click the "Select root directory" field and browse to each subfolder in your workspace folder, and import.